# Test Explorer do Visual Studio não encontra os testes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, testes, tdd

Estou com uma dificuldade no Visual Studio 2013, o Test Explorer não está carregando os testes em momento nenhum, seja após o Build, seja através do `Run Tests / CTRL+R, T`. Alguém tem alguma pista do que possa ser?

Possuo os seguintes pacotes instalados através do NuGet: `xUnit.net`,`xUnit.net: Runners`, `Fluent Assertions`, e o teste abaixo como exemplo:

```cs
using Xunit;
namespace Registro
{
    public class CadastroValidoRecebido
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Usuario_Adicionado_Ao_Sistema()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Segui acertos de diversos links, o que mais pareceu promissor foram as alterações de arquitetura de processador informada no link abaixo, mas o Test Explorer continua sem localizar os testes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533259/why-does-visual-studio-2012-not-find-my-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que me lembro, o Visual Studio não reconhece testes de terceiros (ou seja, que não sejam MSTest) de forma automática, necessitando da instalação de pacotes adicionais ao mesmo.

Dê uma olhada neste para o xunit (não tenho certeza se é este, mas testa ai por favor):

[xUnit.net runner for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099)

Você também pode tentar o Resharper... é pago, mas eu sou absolutamente fã da ferramenta. Pelo que li sobre ele, suporta o xunit via plugins.

Comment: Olá, Miguel. Obrigado pela resposta, erroneamente pensei que o `xUnit.net: Runners` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runners/1.9.2) seria o plug-in que faria funcionar no Visual Studio 2013, após instalar esse informado por você os testes apareceram.

Comment: No meu caso os testes estavam escritos com NUnit 2.0, e por isso tive que adicionar a extensão correspondente de "runner" ao Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Com a versão mais recente do [xUnit.Net](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started.html) já é possível, de acordo com a documentação (http://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-vs.html) é necessário instalar via nuget o pacote `xunit.runner.visualstudio`

Com isso o `xUnit` é integrado com o `Test Explorer`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]